# How can I format string "1900-01-01 08:00:00.000" to just HH:MM and add 30 minutes to it?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, format, timespan

How can I format string `"1900-01-01 08:00:00.000"` to just `HH:MM` and add `30` minutes to it. I've done the following;

```
 p[0]="1900-01-01 08:00:00.000";
 TimeSpan _time = TimeSpan.ParseExact(p[0].ToString(), "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 TimeSpan addtime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
 _time = _time.Add(addtime);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a `TimeSpan`, it is a `DateTime`. A `TimeSpan` represents a length of time, but `DateTime` keeps instant time with date and time of day.

That's why you need to parse it to `DateTime` with a *specific* format with [`DateTime.ParseExact` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx). After that, you can add `30` minutes with [`AddMinutes` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addminutes.aspx).

```
string s = "1900-01-01 08:00:00.000";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", 
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
dt = dt.AddMinutes(30); // 01/01/1900 08:30:00
```

> i want the result to be in HH:mm

If you wanna get this as a `string`, you can use `DateTime.ToString` method like;

```
string result = dt.ToString("HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // 08:30
```

If you wanna get this as a `TimeSpan`, you can use [`TimeOfDay` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofda.aspx) like;

```
TimeSpan ts = dt.TimeOfDay; // {08:30:00}
```

Comment: `TimeSpan ts = dt.AddMinutes(30).TimeOfDay;`

Comment: i want the result to be in HH:mm

Comment: @Soner Gonul there is compile error, you are assigning Boolean to Date variable

Comment: @VishnuBabu You mean as `08:30` as a string or TimeSpan? You can format it for that. Updated my answer.

Comment: @wintersolider Yeah, it was a type. Changed to `TryParseExact` to `ParseExact`.

Comment: @musefan I couldn't decide that OP wants `08:30` as a string or TimeSpan, so I added both. Thanks.